# use of "all" and "everyone"

Tags: pronouns, grammatical-number

Which one of the following sentences is more correct? And why?
Is one of them completely wrong or just less used?

> Not all gets it.
>
> Not everyone gets it.

Comment: It would be "Not all *get* it."

Answer (score 0, accepted):

"All" is one of those difficult English words that can be any of several parts of speech, depending on context. In this instance it is a pronoun being used to mean "all of the people". It always takes the plural form of the verb ("get").

Not all get it.

"Everyone" is an indefinite pronoun meaning every single person and it takes the singular form of the verb "gets".

Not everyone gets it.

"Gets it" is an expression meaning to grasp or understand something, used in informal English.

I find it easier to grasp your meaning when you say "Not everyone gets it" as it tells me straight away that you are referring to people, some of whom don't understand something.

http://partofspeech.org/what-part-of-speech-is-all/
http://www.dailygrammar.com/Lesson-28-Pronouns.htm